# Unity-How to Create two Button events on one Dialogue Tree Script

Tags: unity-game-engine, dialog, composite

So I've been putting together a test program with a simple dialogue tree where you get a question and two option buttons, and when you push one, you go to another level of the tree. So I made a list adding all the tree levels, containing the parameters of the question and both options. I've gotten myself confused though. I'm not really sure how go to add a level to the list if I push a certain button. Aside from an initializer script, I would like to keep it one script. The best I can think of is creating bool functions for if the button is pushed, but I can't really think of how to differentiate it between one button and the other. If anyone has any better ideas for how to go about this. I would appreciate it. Thank you.

```
 public class Level : MonoBehaviour {

 bool button1Pressed;
 bool button2Pressed;

private void Start()
{

    Level Level1 = new Level("Hello", "Hi", "Shut Up");
    Level leaf1 = new Level("Don't be Rude");

    Level Level2 = new Level("What you Doing?", "Not Much", "None of your Business");
    Level leaf2 = new Level("Well Excuuuuse Me");

    Level Level3 = new Level("Can I do that too?", "Sure", "Go Away");
    Level leaf3 = new Level("Fine. Be a Jerk");

    Level Level4 = new Level("This is boring, can we do something else?", "Why not?", "You're boring");
    Level leaf4 = new Level("I'll go be boring somewhere else");

    Level Level5 = new Level("You want ice cream?", "Sounds Good", "I'm allergic");
    Level leaf5 = new Level("ok.......");
    Level leaf = new Level("I Want Chocolate");      

    Level1.add(Level1);
    Level1.add(leaf1);

    Level2.add(Level3);
    Level2.add(leaf2);

    Level3.add(Level4);
    Level3.add(leaf3);

    Level4.add(Level5);
    Level4.add(leaf4);

    Level5.add(leaf5);
    Level5.add(leaf);

    levels.Add(Level1);
    levels.Add(Level2);
    levels.Add(Level3);
    levels.Add(Level4);
    levels.Add(Level5);

}



public static Text Textbox;
public static Button Button1;
public static Button Button2;

    public string OptionA;
    public string OptionB;
    public string Question;

    public string Leaf;

    private List<Level> levels;

    public Level(string question, string optionA, string optionB)
    {
        this.Question = question;
        this.OptionA = optionA;
        this.OptionB = optionB;

        Textbox.text = Question;
        Button1.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = OptionA;
        Button2.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = OptionB;

        levels = new List<Level>();

    }

    public Level(string leaf)
    {
        this.Leaf = leaf;
        Textbox.text = leaf;
    }

    public void add(Level lvl)
    {
        levels.Add(lvl);
    }

    public List<Level> getLevels()
    {
        return levels;
    }

 void OnPointerDown()
{
    button1Pressed = true;
}
void OnPointerUp()
{
    button1Pressed = false;
}

}
```

Initializer

```
public class Initializer : MonoBehaviour {

public Text Textbox;
public Button Button1;
public Button Button2;

void Awake()
{
    Level.Textbox = this.Textbox;
    Level.Button1 = this.Button1;
    Level.Button2 = this.Button2;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two public methods in your script like this

```
public void Button1Pressed()
{
    // Place Button 1 Logic here
}

public void Button2Pressed()
{
    // Place Button 2 Logic here
}
```

Then

1. Go to each button in your scene
2. Find the `On Click ()`  section
3. Click the `+`
4. Drag the object that contains your script with the above code into where it says `None (Object)`
5. Click the dropdow saying `No Function`, and select your script, and the appropriate method to call, for example `Button1Pressed`

[image]

Comment: You can also use [UI.Button.onClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) to assign click event delegates with code.